# How can I work collaboratively on Confluence tables?

Tags: confluence, collaboration

The idea is:

Page A contains a table header, and a lot of child pages (B, C, D), which in turn contain table rows. Page A should display ALL rows of all child pages in ONE table.

No matter which type of include macro I use (include, excerpt-include, multi-excerpt-include) the table macro of page A interprets the results as a SINGLE column. I guess this is due to the execution order of the markup and macros. Does anyone have another solution at hands?

Comment: if i understand you correctly you want to show table on every page and in table show all its childs,isn't it?

Comment: The goal is to have ONE table displayed on the one main page. The child pages hold the rows that are being added to the table on the main page.

Answer (score 0):

An easy work around, although it might not suit your needs, would be to create the tables in .asp pages and then  html-include them on the necessary pages.

I've used .asp pages with html-include a number of times to display content that I couldn't otherwise use in confluence.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Doesn't suit my needs, but I'll vote a helpful here anyway. Thanks so far - well, I can't vote yet. :D

Comment: Sorry that won't work for you. Are you writing the tables in wiki-markup or in html?